# How can I fix app installations still using my old username path after changing my username in Windows 10 using an admin account?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I changed my c/users username using a separate admin account, but when installing some apps and opening some files it tries to go to the old usernames path, any ideas how I can fix this?

I tried to reinstall a program, expected it to install fine, but is now looking for my old username path, additionally I couldn't uninstall it in control panel, so I deleted it from file explorer and emptied the recycle bin

Comment: You may nave better luck with your question on [SU], but I suspect you'll have to provide more information for someone to be able to help you.